# How to use a closure as an argument of another closure?

Tags: closures, rust, type-inference

The code is as follows:

```
fn main() {
  let arg = | | println!("closure");
  let call_twice = | c | { c(); c(); };
  call_twice(arg);
}
```

But the compiler can't inference the correct type of the argument `c`. Error message:

`error: the type of this value must be known in this context`

How can I tell the compiler that the type of the argument is a generic type which impls `Fn`?

---

Edit: If the argument type is trait object, the code can be accepted by compiler. But the indirection isn't necessary, is it?

```
fn main() {
  let arg = | | println!("closure");
  let call_twice = | c :&Fn() | { c(); c(); };
  call_twice(&arg);
}
```

---

Thanks for your answer. But it is the type inference problem that confuse me. Using an `fn` can make the compiler happy.

```
fn main() {
 let arg = | | println!("closure");

 // now compiler knows the argument `c` is a closure
 fn call_twice<F>(c: F) where F:Fn() {c(); c();}

 call_twice(arg);
}
```

Can we add a syntax to support similar functionality? Such as `for<F> | c:F | where F:Fn() {c(); c();}`.

Comment: *Can we add a syntax to support similar functionality?* that's not a question for Stack Overflow, it's something you could ask on reddit (r/rust) or the Rust forums.

Answer (score 3):

Following [the guidelines in the Rust book section on returning closures](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/closures.html#returning-closures) to turn the closure into a `move` closure and boxing it, this is what I had to do to get your program to run at [the Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org):

```
fn main() {
    let arg = Box::new(move || println!("closure"));
    let call_twice = |c: Box<Fn()>| { c(); c(); };
    call_twice(arg);
}
```

Edit to address OP's most recent edit: No. The issue you're dealing with is ultimately not a type inference problem. If it was just type inference, then all we would have had to was tell the closure that `c` was a closure. The actual problem is that "Closure parameters must be local variables and all local variables must have sizes that are known at compile-time." Rust function parameters, on the other hand, apparently don't have this requirement.

Comment: Being a total Rust newb, I've got to say that the tiny bit of indirection in your edit looks a lot cleaner than my solution. I suspect that either boxing or indirection is absolutely required due to Rust's requirement for known parameter sizes at compile time.

Comment: The `move` is unnecessary, here.

Comment: Since this closure isn't actually being returned, wouldn't it be better to put this on the stack with a borrow, instead of on the heap with a box?

Comment: @MatthieuM, you're absolutely right. Can you explain why `move` is unnecessary?

@AlexKnauth, isn't that basically what OP did in his indirection edit?

Comment: @JudahMeek: `move` is only necessary when (1) you capture variables and (2) you cannot borrow one of them long enough. Here, you are not capturing any variable, so it's not necessary.

Comment: You could use `|c: &Fn()|` instead of `|c: Box<Fn()>|`. Not that you'll have to call it as `call_twice(&*arg);`